# What is the time complexity of the f6 function described below

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o

I received a practice exam for an upcoming midterm, but it does not have the answers.
One of the questions I am unsure of is asking for the time complexity of the following function

```
def f6(n):
    if n > 9: 
        return 1 
    else:
        x = 1
        for i in range(0,n):
            x+= f6(n+1)
        return x
```

please help

Comment: Big-O concerns large numbers. Since the function will just return immediately for any `n > 9`, it is `O(1)`. Without the `if` statement you get infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the exponential O(2^n)? The classic exponential function would be:

```py
def exp(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    return 1 + exp(n - 1) + exp(n - 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for n in range(10):
        assert 2**n - 1 == exp(n)
```

That is, two sub-calls per frame, creating a binary tree call stack shape, with lots of repeated work.

While the binary form is common, the generalization of this pattern is O(k^n):

```py
def exp(n, k):
    if n <= 0:
        return 0

    total = 1

    for _ in range(k):
        total += exp(n - 1)

    return total
```

This bears some resemblance to `f6` which looks like it could be O(n^n): every call does O(n) work and spawns `n` child frames recursively.

But `f6` is O(1). How do we get that? First, remove the irrelevant information:

```py
def f6(n):
    if n > 9:
        return

    for _ in range(n):
        f6(n + 1)
```

The critical part is the base case `if n > 9: return`. This puts a limit on growth, which is exactly the thing Big O measures. For any value greater than some constant (9, in this case), we have no increase in the amount of work relative to `n` and we're left with O(1).

It's counterintuitive, but if the base case were `if n > 10e50: return` rather than 9, it'd still be O(1). That 10e50 is still a constant factor, which Big O ignores, as unrealistic as it may seem. Big O is a theoretical growth/scalability heuristic, not a measure of the realistic work that might be done by an algorithm.

Also important is to consider negative values of `n` to ensure that decreases of `n` don't result in growth. `for _ in range(n):` sets the constraint that negative numbers up to and including 0 won't run the loop block where the recursion happens, so we're safe.